# Can the GitHub GraphQL API create files in a repository?

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

The v3 API allowed for the [creation of files](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) but I can't seem to find a way to do this with the v4 GraphQL API. Is it currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [discussion about creating a repository with `v4`](https://platform.github.community/t/schema-request-create-repository-and-get-repository-contents/1833) and as the guy from github staff said:

> "(they) don’t currently provide a rough estimate of when specific
>   features will ship."

and I guess it's the same with file creation.

Comment: You link is dead.

Comment: link reference is dead.